# How to access MongoDB rather than JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb, controller

I have created a little application that implemented a JSON file as the data store. I'm trying to learn about MEAN, so I'm trying to convert it to a NODE.js app.

I have created a mongoDB importing my JSON file using mongoimport. The db is there and connected. When I put http://localhost:3000/api/characters into the browser it returns JSON for all the characters.
I have built a connection string and required it into my controller as follows...

```
// FROM node app characters.controller.js
var dbconn = require('../data/dbconnection.js');
var characterData = require('../data/characters.json');

module.exports.charactersGetAll = function(req, res) {

    var db = dbconn.get();
    var collection = db.collection('characters');

    // Get the documents from the collection
    // Need to use to Array() as its only a cursor if you don't
    collection
        .find()
        .toArray(function(err, docs) {
            console.log("Found characters!", docs);
            res
                .status(200)
                .json(docs);
        });

    //console.log('db', db);
    //console.log("GET the Characters");
    //console.log(req.query);
    res
        .status(200)
        .json(characterData);
};

module.exports.charactersGetOne = function(req, res) {
    var charId = req.params.id;
    var thisChar = characterData[charId];
    console.log("GET characterId", charId);
    res
        .status(200)
        .json(thisChar);
};
```

From the non-NODE version of the app, I call in the JSON data as follows in my main.js file:

```
//FROM TRADITIONAL HTML/JS application

// Get JSON and callback so JSON can be stored globally
$.getJSON('people.json', callback);
// Populate faces and names in HTML
function callback(data) {
    /*optional stuff to do after success  */
    var $charNames = $('.char-names');
    var $faceImage = $('.faces');

    $.each(data, function(index, val) {
        console.log("success");
        /* iterate through array or object */
        /* .eq() method constructs new object from one element from set  */
        $charNames.eq(index).text(val.name);
        $faceImage.eq(index).attr('src', val.image);
        //Push all JSON to array
        allTheCharacters.push(val);
        allTheCharactersComp.push(val);
    });

}
```

What I want to ask is – Is there a simple way I can access the mongoDB in the non-NODE main.js file instead of using the $.getJSON method and how would I add/adapt this for the node characters.controller.js

Hopefully, I am making sense. Apologies in advance for any misunderstanding.